# Postgres function - using table mapping to update value

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have a general question. I have a function that creates a file. However, within that function presently I am hard coding the file name pattern based on argument inputs. Now I have come to a point where I need to have more than one file name pattern. I devised a way of using another table as the file name map that the function can simply call if the user inputs that file name pattern id. Here is my example to help better illustrate my point:

Here is the table creation and data insertion for referential purposes:

```
    create table some_schema.file_mapper(
        mapper_id integer not null,
        file_name_template varchar);

    insert into some_schema.file_mapper (mapper_id, file_name_template)
    values
    (1, '||v_first_name||''_''||v_last_name||')
    (2, '||v_last_name||''_''||v_first_name||')
    (3, '||v_last_name||''_''||v_last_name||');
```

Now the function itself

```
create or replace function some_schema.some_function(integer)

returns varchar as

$body$

Declare

v_filename_config_id alias for $1;
v_filename           varchar;
v_first_name         varchar;
v_last_name          varchar;
cmd                  text;

Begin

v_first_name :='Joe';
v_last_name  :='Shmoe';

cmd := 'select file_name_template
        from some_schema.file_mapper
        where mapper_id = '||v_filename_config||'';
execute cmd into v_filename;

raise notice 'checking "%"',v_filename;

return 'done';
end;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now that I have this. I want to be able to mix and match file name patterns. So for instance I wanted to use mapper_id 3, I would expect a returned file of "Shmoe_Shmoe.csv" if I execute the script:

```
select from some_schema.some_function(2)
```

The Problem is whenever I get it to read the "v_filename" variable it will not evaluate and return the values from the function's variables. Originally, I believed it to be a quoting issue(and it probably still is). After messing with the quoting I have gotten about as far the error below:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "_"
LINE 4: ...s/dir/someplace/||v_last_name||'_'||v_firs...
                                                         ^
QUERY:  copy(
             select * 
             from some_schema.some_table)
             to '/dir/someplace/||v_last_name||'_'||v_first_name||.csv/;
             DELIMITER,
             csv HEADER;
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function some_schema.some_function(integer) line 27 at EXECUTE statement
```

As you can tell it is pretty much telling me it is a quoting issue. Is there a way I can get the function to properly evaluate the variable and return the proper file name? Let me know if I am not clear and need to elaborate.

Comment: Use the format() function instead of string concatenation to construct the command. This will avoid most of your quoting problems.

Comment: so something like this example?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE

Comment: Yes, just above 39.5.5. but you dont have to execute immediately, you can first do `stmt = format( ...);` and execute the resulting string later, using `execute stmt;`

Comment: @wildplasser looks like I am getting another error:

I changed the cmd block to this:

    cmd := format('copy(
               select * 
                 from some_schema.some_table)
                 to ''/dir/someplace/%I.csv/'';
                 DELIMITER,
                 csv HEADER;',v_filename);
                 execute cmd;

I am still getting a quoting error... the issue I having is not so much the quoting issue, but making sure that my v_filename variable is properly evaluated and displays the proper name...

Comment: `...  to '/dir/someplace/%L.csv/'` v_filename is *not* an identifier ! (BTW You can inspect the resulting string with a `RAISE NOTICE %" , cmd;`

Comment: @wildplasser hm... I was trying to be clever. But, I am not sure if this will ever work as intended. My original goal was to eliminate having to add more structure and multiple code blocks based on the "mapper_id" . What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Yes, doing the notice check does return unintended result of
    
    "'||v_last_name||_||v_first_name||'"

Sorry for the two-pronged question.

Comment: In short: get rid of the string concatenation (imagine column names with spaces in them ...) and use format() for building dynamic SQL queries. See my answer.

Comment: @wildplasser btw I see what you mean about not being an identifier. Should have use "L". Thanks for that. I was being lazy and didn't fully look that up.

Comment: @wildplasser noted and will do. I'll clean this up and give it another shot.

Comment: Returning the query string is another debugging trick. (your function intended to return a varchar, but never returned any value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This more or less illustrates the usage of `format()`. (Slightly reduced wrt the original question):

```
CREATE TABLE file_mapper
        ( mapper_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        ,  file_name_template TEXT
        );
INSERT INTO file_mapper(mapper_id, file_name_template) VALUES (1,'one'), (2, 'two');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dump_the_shit(INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR AS
$body$

DECLARE

v_filename_config_id alias for $1;
v_filename           VARCHAR;
name_cmd                  TEXT;
copy_cmd                  TEXT;

BEGIN

name_cmd := format( e'select file_name_template
        from file_mapper
        where mapper_id = %L;', v_filename_config_id );

EXECUTE name_cmd into v_filename;
RAISE NOTICE 'V_filename := %', v_filename;

copy_cmd := format( e'copy(
             select * 
             from %I)
             to \'/tmp/%s.csv\'
             csv HEADER;' , 'file_mapper' , v_filename);

EXECUTE copy_cmd;

RETURN copy_cmd;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT dump_the_shit(1);
```

---

[format function description](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

summary:

- use %I for identifiers (tablenames and column names) [ `FROM %I` ]
- use %L for literals such as query constants [ `WHERE the_date = %L` ]
- use %s for ordinary strings [ `to \'/tmp/%s.csv\'` ]

Comment: Dude. Yo, you totally nailed both of my questions. Man. Thank you!